# How to get count and types of method parameters using org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to extract method parameters information from Java class bytecode using asm `MethodVisitor`. `visitParameter` method of `MethodVisitor` is not called (because no parameter names are present in compiled class file). How can i get count of method parameters and their types?

The only thing I've found so far is `desc` parameter of `visitMethod` from `MethodVisitor`. I can copy-paste `TraceSignatureVisitor` class from asm-util, rewrite about 50 lines of code to store parameters declarations into List/array instead of single `StringBuffer`.

Another option is suggested by in answer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061588/get-function-arguments-values-using-java-asm-for-bytecode-instrimentation":

> The number of arguments to the method can be computed from the method description using the code in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/VijayKrishna/6160036. Using the `parseMethodArguments(String desc)` method you can easily compute the number of arguments to the method.

From my point of view copy-pasting and rewriting `TraceSignatureVisitor` is still better.

But i suppose there **should be** more simple way to work with method signatures in asm-util. Is there?

Comment: [`Type.getArgumentTypes(String methodDescriptor)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getArgumentTypes(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Holder, that's an answer i looked for! thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASM has an abstract for that purpose, [`Type`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html).

Instances of `Type` may represent a primitive type, a reference type, or a method type. So you can first get a type to represent the method type from the descriptor string, followed by querying it for the parameter types and return type.

```java
String desc = "(Ljava/lang/String;I[[ZJ)D";

Type methodType = Type.getMethodType(desc);
int sizes = methodType.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes();
System.out.println("return type: "
    + methodType.getReturnType().getClassName() + " (" +(sizes & 3) + ')');

Type[] argTypes = methodType.getArgumentTypes();
System.out.println(argTypes.length + " arguments (" + (sizes >> 2) + ')');
for (int ix = 0; ix < argTypes.length; ix++) {
    System.out.println("arg" + ix + ": " + argTypes[ix].getClassName());
}
```

The sizes returned by `getArgumentsAndReturnSizes()` refer to local variables and operand stack entries, where `long` and `double` count as two. It also accounts for the implied `this` parameter, which is convenient for an instance method but requires the caller to subtract one for `static` methods.

The example prints

```
return type: double (2)
4 arguments (6)
arg0: java.lang.String
arg1: int
arg2: boolean[][]
arg3: long
```

If you are interested in one of the features only, you can get it directly using one of the static methods of the `Type` class.

```java
int sizes = Type.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes(desc);
Type ret = Type.getReturnType(desc);
Type[] argTypes = Type.getArgumentTypes(desc);
```